# Jquery - custom HTML for template - strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var $template;
$.get('/templates/searchTemplate.tmpl', function(HTMLres) {
    $template = $(HTMLres);
});
$.each(data.results, function(key, value) {
    $template.find('button').off().on('click', function() { console.log('you clicked me') });
    $template.find('.media-body > strong').html(value.firstname + ' ' + value.lastname);
    $template.find('.email').html(value.mail);
    $template.find('.phone').html(value.phone);
    $template.find('.age').html(value.age);
    $('#searchRsults').append($template);
});
```

When I try to use this code instead of having the template file to be Appended to the UL element, this will clear the previous append and append the next result to the UL element.

The template file is just a -> `<LI> </LI>` with some spans.

Note that if I put the   |`$.get (template)` in the `$.each` part of the code everything works like it supposed to be all the `<LI> </LI>` element are appended one after another.

But doing so it makes a lot of request for the template file. On every iteration actually.

Even if I use the `.DONE` after the Ajax request still the result is the same the `<LI> </LI>` gets overwritten not appended

Comment: I think you have some problems with async constructions - your request may not be completed yet, but your iterator starts already fcreating your form. Definitely you should do this on promise complete event.

Comment: like I commented just now - @zakaria - tested with $.get().done() and put my code there still the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `each()` inside the success callback so the `$template` will be available, else you're trying to use the `$template` when it's not returned yet from the asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request :

```
var $template;
$.get('/templates/searchTemplate.tmpl', function(HTMLres) {
    $template = $(HTMLres);

    $.each(data.results, function(key, value) {
        $template.find('button').off().on('click', function() { console.log('you clicked me') });
        $template.find('.media-body > strong').html(value.firstname + ' ' + value.lastname);
        $template.find('.email').html(value.mail);
        $template.find('.phone').html(value.phone);
        $template.find('.age').html(value.age);
        $('#searchRsults').append($template);
    });
});
```

Take a look to **[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tested what you have suggested, the result is the same. Even tested with $.get().done() and have my code in the .done part where everything is executed after request is compleated and done - nothing ...

Comment: The `done` callback is the same as you've now, if nothing that mean your `/templates/searchTemplate.tmpl` doesn't return the expected result, try to  debug it `console.log($template)`.

Comment: What the `console.log($template)` gives you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getResults(searchTerm){
           return $.get("/api/search", { 'searchFor': keyword });
        }

function getTemplate(){
            return $.get('/templates/searchTemplate.tmpl')
        }

$.when(getResults(keyword), getTemplate())
            .done(function(result1, result2){
                $('ul#searchRsults').empty();
                if (result1[0].results.indexOf('no results') != 0) {
                    $.each(result1[0].results, function(key, value) {

                        var $template = $(result2[0]);
                            $template.find('.img-avatar').html(img);
                            $template.find('button').off().on('click', function() { console.log('you clicked me') });
                            $template.find('.media-body > strong').html(value.firstname + ' ' + value.lastname);
                            $template.find('.email').html(value.mail);
                            $template.find('.phone').html(value.phone);
                            $template.find('.age').html(value.age);
                            $('#searchRsults').append($template);
                    });
            }
        })
```

after some read - I ended with this solution, in chrome console the request for template is made only once. Hope this helps sombady